# Matlab: Position y axis label to top

Tags: matlab

Every time reader reads the graph, they have to rotate their head to read the y-axis. After reading the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ylabel.html) and search the internet, I still cannot figure it out. How can I position the y axis label not to the left side of the y-axis, but on the top of the y-axis.

E.g.
[image]

to
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create the `ylabel` object and then manually adjust its properties : `'Position'` and `'Rotation'`:

```
plot(1:.1:10, (1:.1:10).^2); % example plot
t = title('Title');
y = ylabel('ylabel');
vf = 1.125; % vertical factor. Adjust manually
dy = .55; % horizontal offset. Adjust manually
tpos = get(t, 'Position');
theight = tpos(2);
ypos = get(y, 'Position');
set(y, 'Position', [ypos(1)+dy tpos(2)*1.02 ypos(3)], 'Rotation', 0)
```

This gives the following figure:

[image]